# Finding an unmatched paranthesis in a file

Tags: command-line

So I have this huge file (a SharePoint rendering templates file, if you're interested). The problem is, it doesn't work, because somewhere inside that file, in a code block, there is an unmatched '('. How do I find it? I'm on a Windows machine, but I have all the GNU command-line utilities installed.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](http://xkcd.com/859/).

Comment: You can always go through it by hand. ;) I have an effective mental algorithm that I use for this kind of debugging. I should code up a Perl script to automate it though, at some point. :)

Comment: @sidran32, you just keep a count, and see where it goes negative?

Comment: @soandos More or less. Or where it stays positive. :) It also helps that compilers will start throwing errors directly after the line where the error is. Before I realized how to do that kind of debugging properly, it really was a nightmare to try and fix. :P One mismatched curly brace, missing semicolon, or mismatched parenthesis can trigger hundreds of errors.

Comment: To be honest, with proper indentation, it is almost never hard to fix. If you don't have that, it can be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the emacs command `M-x check-parens<RET>.`

Turning on `show-paren-mode` would also probably be a good idea.

Comment: I'm more of a Vim person, but looks like this is my only option. Thanks!